# Accessing Chrome Remote Desktop Without Signing Into Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop, remote-access, chrome-remote-desktop

Can I setup Chrome Remote Desktop access on a host machine without having to log into Chrome on that machine?

I don't want to sync all of my Google account to the Chrome browser on that machine or even trust it with my Google password.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, just go to https://remotedesktop.google.com/headless on a device that you don't mind signing into with your Google account, and it will walk you through setting up access to the remote machine.

If that doesn't work you can try these manual instructions for Windows:

1. [Install Chrome Remote Desktop on that machine](https://dl.google.com/edgedl/chrome-remote-desktop/chromeremotedesktophost.msi)
2. Get an [auth code](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&approval_prompt=auto&redirect_uri=https://remotedesktop.google.com/_/oauthredirect&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromoting.directory%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&client_id=440925447803-avn2sj1kc099s0r7v62je5s339mu0am1.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=code) (note the client ID is from chromium)
3. Find the auth code from the `code=` parameter of the blank page you get navigated to. It will look something like `4/gJ_BAIf5ncx7yWD56Zduwv09RLpYQu3lhaPPXTozXi4`
4. On that machine run (in an Administrator shell): `"%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Google\Chrome Remote Desktop\<VERSION_YOU_INSTALLED>\remoting_start_host.exe" --code="MY_AUTH_CODE" --redirect-url="https://talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/blank" --name="MY_REMOTE_NAME"`
5. Pick a PIN and use it to connect later

For manual instructions for Linux try this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/795703/chrome-remote-desktop-access-to-headless-ubuntu-server-16-04-machine/953269#953269)

Comment: The token will expire after several minutes, so do not worry if you get an error `Couldn't start host: OAuth error.`  Simply obtain another token and try again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57911277/oauth-error-when-attempting-to-start-host-for-chrome-remote-desktop-on-gce

Comment: The auth code link is broke for me now. Worked just a few days ago. An alternate link: https://remotedesktop.google.com/headless

Comment: @MichaelE I just updated the auth code link, I think this new one will work. But most people really should just use https://remotedesktop.google.com/headless

Comment: Any idea how to do the same thing on macOS?